# Hat position is wrong in iOS app, scrolls with page

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, winter-bash-2015

When visiting my profile on the mobile app, my hat scrolls with the page:

[image: hat scroll]

It doesn't stay linked to my icon at the top.
I'm on an iPhone 6+ running iOS 9.2 and version 1.4.1 of the SE app.

Comment: Voting to leave this bug open since it's so funny!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update** Actually it shipped the next day!

---

This will be fixed either next week or in December 2016.

I am so sad about this.  Like, really, really sad.

WinterBash hats are on a separate overlay view which updates its content offset on scroll as follows:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.winterBashOverlayView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

Unfortunately, I inserted this method inside a `#ifdef DEBUG` block so it worked perfectly during development but is completely excluded from the release.

Comment: Ow. That's probably worth an expedited review request, it's somewhat time sensitive and we're going into the holidays.

Comment: Meh, why not use swift?

Comment: @bjb568 Because SENetworkViewController.m was created Feb 21, 2014 and Swift 1.0 was announced on June 2, 2014.

Comment: Scrolling due to toggling comment menu causes similar problem. Should I post a new question about it?

Comment: @unarist I see what you mean.  It only happens if you toggle the menu when scrolled near the bottom.  You can add a new issue if you want but I'm fixing it now.

Comment: Well, I will forget this until next build :-)

Comment: @unarist That will be fixed in the next build, but the animation won't be great.  UITableView does confusing things when it scrolls during an animation.

Comment: Thanks for being honest! But, this is not [tag:status-completed] then. [tag:status-planned] perhaps.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This bug seems to be fixed in beta release.

Comment: @unarist but these days, most people are using the official release, not beta. So I think it's more proper to mark completed only when the fix is pushed to the release channel, otherwise it will be quite confusing. Brian, what do you think?

Comment: @ShadowWizard my practice is to mark status complete when I've committed the change to git. None of the other statuses seem appropriate and this helps me process the queue. As for this feature, it's actually in the review queue with an expedited review request.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, guess after all it doesn't really matter - we can still close the new reports as duplicate of this, regardless of the status.

Comment: @odnU The expedited review was a great idea. We got a one day turn around.

Comment: @BrianNickel That's great! I haven't had great luck with them, but that could be because none of my apps are terribly critical, and, by extension, none of my fixes.

Comment: @BrianNickel The table jumps around a lot when I scroll down slowly and hold. Is it related somehow to this?